# Azure functions queue trigger - how to put items back into the queue if we failed?

Tags: azure-functions

I am using Azure Functions with a queue trigger.

When the function runs, it takes an item off the Azure Queue. However, sometimes my processing will fail and in that case, I want to requeue the item and have it processed later.

How can one achieve that in Azure Functions and using Node.js?

Comment: Have you tried just throwing an exception?

Comment: @HenryBeen Uhm, haven't. If I throw an exception, the function keeps running until the 5 minutes time limit. I'll try, thanks.

Comment: The function will try to process the message for 5 times as default and moves the item to poison queue. It will be removed from the original queue. if you want to control the number of times the function should reprocess, you can set the maxDequeueCount property in host.json.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-host-json

Comment: I would love to have that functionality. Say we process a queue message, if fails, put it back to queue with invisibility for a few hours. Once it shows up again, try to process again. At some point if dequeue point reaches say 5, report success and queue message will be deleted. Grr I wish this was available. We need a way to control if message can be put back to queue.

Comment: @dotsa this is already possible. I've posted a code sample below

Answer (score 3):

The workaround I did was to create a bind to the same queue that triggers the function.

```
 [FunctionName("FunctionsQueueTrigger")]
    public static async Task Run(
        [QueueTrigger("101functionsqueue")] string myQueueItem,
        [Queue("101functionsqueue")]  IAsyncCollector<string> myQueue)
```

In my case, I wanted to put the item back to the queue if a storage exception was thrown with the code 412 (Precondition Failed).

```
catch (StorageException ex)
        {
            if (ex.RequestInformation.HttpStatusCode == (int)System.Net.HttpStatusCode.PreconditionFailed) //412
            {
                log.LogWarning($"Putting item back to queue due to {ex.Message} error.");
                await myQueue.AddAsync(myQueueItem);
            }
        }
```

In the end, the function removes the current item from the queue, but a new one with the same content is added.

It may be not the best solution but worked fine for me.

Comment: Wouldn't putting the item back on the queue trigger the function again, and recursively keep putting it back on the queue?

Comment: @LeeHarrison Yes, if the error 412 persists and never stops. But fortunately it's not the case for this error, at least I have an application running in production env with millions of data being processed and it never got into this endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

Queue triggers follows peek-lock pattern. This means that, as messages are dequeued, they are marked as invisible and associated with a timeout managed by the Storage service.

When the function starts, it starts processing a message under the following conditions.

- If the function is successful, then the function execution completes and the message is deleted.
- If the function fails, then the message visibility is reset. After being reset, the message is reprocessed the next time the function requests a new message.
- If the function never completes due to a crash, the message visibility expires and the message re-appears in the queue.

All of the visibility mechanics are handled by the Storage service, not the Functions runtime.

Check further in: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-queue-trigger?tabs=in-process%2Cextensionv5&pivots=programming-language-javascript#peek-lock

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the ServiceBusClient to put them back on the queue with a delay of your choosing.

You'll need to add the [Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus) to your Azure Function.

Here is the function:

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using QueueExample.Data;

namespace QueueExample
{
    public class QueueFunction
    {
        private readonly IQueueService _queueService;

        public QueueFunction(IQueueService queueService)
        {
            _queueService = queueService;
        }

        [FunctionName("YatesQueueTrigger")]
        public async Task Run([ServiceBusTrigger("%MyQueueName%", Connection = "MyQueueConnection")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            Deal someDeal = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Deal>(myQueueItem);
            if (someDeal != null && someDeal.IsGoodDeal == false)
            {
                someDeal.IsGoodDeal = true;
                await _queueService.SendMessageAsync(someDeal, 2); // Put it back on the queue with a 2 minute delay

                log.LogWarning($"Bad deal re-queued: {myQueueItem}");
            }
            else
            {
                log.LogInformation($"Good deal: {myQueueItem}");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Notes

- You may also want to add a flag to tell yourself how many times this has been done so that you don't continue to put it back on the queue.

Here is the service I'm injecting to put them back on the queue with a delay:

```cs
using Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using QueueExample.Data;
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace QueueExample;

public interface IQueueService
{
    Task SendMessageAsync(Deal dealToQueue, int delayInMinutes);
}

public class QueueService : IQueueService
{
    private readonly ServiceBusSettings _settings;
    private readonly ServiceBusClient _serviceBusClient;

    public QueueService(ServiceBusSettings settings)
    {
        _settings = settings;
        _serviceBusClient = new ServiceBusClient(settings.QueueConnectionString);
    }

    public async Task SendMessageAsync(Deal dealToQueue, int delayInMinutes)
    {
        await using var sender = _serviceBusClient.CreateSender(_settings.QueueName);

        ServiceBusMessage message = new ServiceBusMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dealToQueue))
        {
            ScheduledEnqueueTime = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(delayInMinutes))
        };

        await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

In case someone is looking for an answer later, here's a code sample that uses the [imago-azure-storage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/imago-azure-storage) package:

```
const { Queues } = require('imago-azure-storage');
const q = new Queues(storageAccount, storageKey);

const QUEUE_NAME = 'testqueue';

(async() => {
    // Create the queue if it does not exist yet:
    await q.initializeQueues([QUEUE_NAME]);

    // Write a sample item to the queue:
    await q.put(QUEUE_NAME, { test: 12345 });

    // Retrieve up to 10 items, and if any of them fail,
    // retry processing them after 3600 seconds:
    let items = await q.fetch(QUEUE_NAME, 10, 3600);
    for (const { item, message } of items) {
        try {
          console.log(item);
          await doSomeWork(item); // <-- your function here

          // Items processed successfully, delete it from queue:
          await q.commit(message);
        } catch (error) {
          // Ignore errors, the item will be requeued automatically
          // in 3600 seconds.
        }
    }
})();
```

Comment: This is not the same. What you have here is the variation of one time timer that fetches and does work on batch of queue messages. What we are taking about is the true queue trigger that has this functionality.